# storing large data in files vs tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, storage

So I am working on this `website` where people can post articles. My colleague suggested storing  all the meta-data of an article `(user, title, dates etc)` in a table and the actual article body as a file in the server.

A data structure would look like:

```
post_id      post_user_id     post_title       post_body     post_date     etc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            1                My First Post    1_1.txt       2014-07-07    ...
2            1                My First Post    2_1.txt       2014-07-07    ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now we would get the record of the post and then locate where it is by

```
$post_id . "_" . $post_user_id . ".txt";
```

He says that this will reduce the size of the tables and on the long run make it faster to access. I am not sure about this and wanted to ask if there are any issues in this design.

Comment: reduce the size of the tables, obviously but its put onto the filesystem instead. make it faster to access, not true as is it will involve more code and filesystem access which is slower. Its a pretty bad suggestion

Comment: Much easier to search if it's in the db.

Comment: Besides what's already been said (slow search, slow access) there's no need for the post_body field in the method above, because all files would be stored in a uniquely named file based on other values in the table.

Comment: The post body field is there only in case tomorrow something changes..and we cannot dynamically generate the file name for any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first risk that pops into my mind is *data corruption*. Following the design, you are *splitting* the information into two fragments, even though both pieces are dependant from one another :

- A file has to exist for each metadata entry (or you'll end up with *not found* errors for entries supposed to exist).
- A metadata entry has to exist for each file (or you'll end up with garbage).

Using the database only has one big advantage : it is very probably *relational*. This means that you actually **can** set up rules to prevent the two scenarios above to occur (you could use an SQL `CASCADE DELETE` for instance, or put every piece of information in one table). Keeping these *relations* between two data backends is going to be a tricky thing to setup.

Another important thing to remember : data stored in a SQL database isn't sent to a magical place far from your drive. When you add an entry into your database, you write to your database files. For instance, those files are stored in `/var/lib/mysql` for MySQL engines. Writing to other files does not make that much of a difference...

Next thing : time. Accessing a database is fast once it's opened, all it takes is query processing. Accessing files (and that is, once per article) may be heavier : files need to be opened (including privileges checks, ...), read (line-by-line according to your buffer size) and closed. Of course, you can add to that all the programming it would take to link those files to their metadata...

To me, this design adds unecessary complexity to the application. You could store everything in the database, *centralise*. You'll use pretty much the same amount of disk space in both cases, yet looking-up/accessing each article file separately (while keeping it connected with its DB metadata) will certainly waste some time.

> Design for simplicity; add complexity only where you must. *(Eric S. Raymond)*

Answer (score 1):

This could look like a *good idea* is those posts are **NEVER** edited. Access to a file could take a while, and if your user wants to edit a lot of times his post, storing the content in a file is not a great idea. SQL support well large text values (as WYSIWYG text), dont be afraid to store them in your `Post` table.

Additionally, your filesystem will take ways more time to read and writes datas stored in files than in database.

Everything will depend of the number of post you want to store, and if you users **can edit or not** their posts.

Comment: So, which approach is better, the file system or a database, if there will be a large number of articles, as Wikipedia has, for example?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I think that database with cache is the best way to handle this kind of feature.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree, in a production environment it is generally recommended to let the file system keep track of **files** and the database to hold on to the metadata.

However, I have mostly heard this philosophy be applicable to `BLOG` types and Images. Because even large articles are relatively small, a `TEXT` data type can suffice and even make it easier to edit, draw from, and search as needed. \

(hence I agree with Rémi Delhaye, who answered this just as I was writing this post)

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem is much more likely to have higher latency and files can 'go missing' where a database record is less likely to.

If the contents of the field is too large in the case of SQL Server then you could look at the FileStream API in newer versions.

Really though, either approach is valid in my opinion. With a file you don't have to worry about the database mangling the content if you make a mistake during escaping or something.

Beware if you're writing your code on a case-insensitive filesystem and running on a case-sensitive one in production- filename case matters so it can be another way to lose access to your files later on or unexpectedly once the application is deployed.